# Can a single word refer to two or more things at once?

Tags: grammar

> 3. a. A body of persons sent to conduct negotiations or establish relations with a foreign country.
>
> b. The business with which such a body of persons is charged.
>
> c. A permanent diplomatic office abroad.
>
> d. A body of experts or dignitaries sent to a foreign country.

I am wondering if the word mission for example can be used to refer to all of a), b), c), d) all at once.

For example:

The U.S. used all of its missions (diplomatic, inspectors, dignatories, diplomatic offices, etc.) to put pressure on Iran.

Comment: Ambiguity between senses *a,c,d* will often be harmless, but I would not wish to risk confusing *b* with any of the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; however, in this case the result would be unclear to the listener or reader. A word can have several meanings. But when you *use* the word, we expect the word to take on a *single* one of those meanings -- unless the context clearly shows otherwise as you do here.

In your example, "missions (diplomatic, ..., etc.)" makes it clear that we're using multiple meanings for "mission".

If you omitted the clarification, "...used all of its missions to put pressure on...", I would interpret that sentence as multiple occurrences of the *same* meaning. For example, embassy personnel in different locations/cities around the world having some relevance to pressuring Iran.